# arcpy custom script tool to find and replace floats and ints?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I created a custom script tool that can find and replace text. See the image link for what my tool interface looks like too, and I'll point out the find and replace fields are both set to string in their data types. I'm really not experienced in custom script tools, and would like to know how to make some "buttons" or checkboxes of sorts to choose between finding and replacing strings or floats or integers. Would that be a tool validation-side issue or a script-side issue?

[image]

```
import arcpy

FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
oldText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
replaceText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
targetField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)


queryString = targetField + ' = ' + "'" + oldText + "'"

try:

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC, (targetField), queryString) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == oldText:
            row[0] = replaceText
            cursor.updateRow(row)

            arcpy.AddMessage("String where " + queryString + " found and replaced with " + replaceText)

except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
    arcpy.AddError("Failed to find and replace where " + queryString)
```

Comment: Especially if you are new to Python, I would recommend removing try/except statements when testing and from any code snippets posted here because they can mask error messages that Python provides to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easiest to add a new parameter of [Value List](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm#GUID-3CB5FAF4-43DD-4C84-8AFE-08039A72B3E0) type. There you could specify the data type to work with (strings, floats, integers etc).

When it's done, you can add some if-else logic in the script body (no validation involved at all), casting to `str(), int(), float()`.

Optionally, you could use [tool validation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/customizing-script-tool-behavior.htm) to check the data type for the field so it matches the chosen data type:

```
field = arcpy.ListFields(fc,targetField)[0]
if field.type != chosen_type:
    #add error/warning for the parameter
```

PS. Be careful constructing the strings with lots of quotes; this is because field need to be delimited differently depending on your data source. You might want to let your tool work as expected regardless the source the feature class is coming from (SDE, personal, file gdb). Wherever possible, try to use the [field delimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm).